# Write a method for a generic type that is required to implement an interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface

Assume there is a Class called A which has a method as follows:

```
public void SomeMethod<T>(ref T para1)
{
    ...
}
```

Now I have an interface (lets call it ITest) that enforces a method (lets call it RequiredMethod()) and there are a bunch of classes that implement this interface.

In the declaration of SomeMethod, how can I mention that T needs to implement ITest so that I can do something like this?

```
public void SomeMethod<T implements ITest>(ref T para1)
{
    ...
    para1.RequiredMethod();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Are you really sure you need to be passing the parameter by reference?  This is usually not required in general, and particularly in generic methods.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [generic constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

```
public void SomeMethod<T>(ref T para1)
    where T : ITest
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: That did the trick! thank you! the interface needs to be public as well else there is an accessibility problem

Answer (score 3):

You can use the C# `where` keyword for this. [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx)

```
public void SomeMethod<T>(ref T para1) where T : ITest
{
    ...
    para1.RequiredMethod();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a where to SomeMethod.

```
public void SomeMethod<T>(ref T para1) where T:ITest
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx

Answer (score -3):

Why not implement your interface in the declaration of your T class instead of in the method?

Comment: Can you show an example of how you imagine that would look?

Comment: My mistake... I misread the question.  I thought he was using T as a class name, not a generic.